Book about a homeless girl who volunteers at a shady facility for money
It's probably been a decade since I read this book. At the time it was released its cover was silver/metallic gray and had had a girl with blond hair (or white hair due to the metallic front) facing me, the reader. On the spine and back of the book, it shifted from a metallic silver to an ocean blue.
The story begins with a homeless girl who goes to see her little brother who is hiding in what seems to be an abandoned hut/room (?). She carries him a new coat because it's winter and the cold seems to be getting progressively worse. She wants to provide for her brother so she ends up going to this clinic/facility (?) where she discusses with these workers about a program they're running, where she'd be paid for putting a chip inside of her head and allowing herself to be unconscious for someone (who I believe isn't able-bodied) to take over and have a chance to function in a new body. She agrees, gets the chip inserted and lays down on a table in a room where, noticeably, there are other people who are also volunteering their bodies to the program.
Now throughout the story, the girl at first does not recall what happens when she is unconscious, but over time she learns about the old woman who uses her body. Fast forward, the girl wakes up (assuming earlier than she was supposed to) and finds herself in a building she’s never seen before, but immediately knows it ties to the old lady she's lent her body to. She walks around and explores the rooms, where she eventually opens a drawer and finds a gun (Unsure if it was a .45 Caliber Pistol or a Revolver). At this point, the elderly woman begins to talk to the girl inside her own mind, and for the first time they manage to have what seems to be a full-on conversation. I was unable to finish the end of the book beyond this point.

This is Starters (2012) by Lissa Price.
It's the first book in the Starters duology, the follow-up being Enders (2013).
The first book has been published with a few different covers, but the first edition hardcover matches your description, with the front cover showing the face of a white-haired girl on a metallic background, and the spine and back cover both being blue.



According to a review at WordPress, the story takes in a future Los Angeles in the aftermath of a war that killed everyone between the ages of 20 and 60, leaving only the elderly, known as 'Enders,' and the young, known as 'Starters.'
The protagonist, Callie Woodland, is a 16-year-old orphan struggling to provide for herself and her sick younger brother, Tyler. Out of desperation, she goes to a company called Prime Destinations, which enables Starters to rent their bodies out to Enders via the use of implanted neurochips. (A Starter's consciousness goes to 'sleep' within their own body while it's being occupied by the consciousness of an Ender.)
Callie's first two rentals go well, but the third time, something goes awry and she wakes up three weeks before she's supposed to while still in the life of the wealthy Ender renting her body. What's more, she starts hearing the voice of that Ender in her head, warning her not to go back to Prime Destinations.

Callie Woodland‘s futuristic Los Angeles is filled with terrible chaos. The Spore Wars killed everyone between the ages of twenty and sixty leaving  the very young, the Starters and the very old, the Enders. Orphaned, Callie must fend and provide for herself and her sickly brother Tyler, and she does just that with some help from former neighbor and fellow orphan Michael. But times become more dire as Tyler’s illness progress for worse. Callie must make hard decisions which eventually led her to Prime Destinations also known as the body bank.
If you’re a moneyed Ender, you go to Prime Destinations to relive being young but if you’re an unclaimed Starter, you go there to temporarily sign off your body for someone else to use and claim in exchange for money.
Desperate, Callie goes to Prime Destinations and becomes one of their body donors. She’s scrubbed and remade, and fitted with a neurochip in her head to enable the renter to control her body. Her first two rentals went well but just when she thought things are going to go smoothly her third and final one goes awry. A week into her supposedly month-long rental, Callie wakes up inside a bar which she knows is entirely wrong. Then she starts hearing a voice inside her head, the voice of the Ender renting her body, warning her not to go back to the body bank. Fearing that Prime may not pay her if they learn about the glitch in her chip, she abides but soon she realizes that her renter has plans of her own and that everything and everyone else around her isn’t what they seem to be. Callie knows she must do something.

According to the Wikipedia page, the Ender renting Callie's body plans to bring down Prime Destinations.

Callie initially relishes the chance to live a lavish life where she wants for nothing and even finds herself dating the grandson of a U.S. Senator, but soon discovers that the Ender she's linked to has big plans to bring down the Body Bank, and not everyone she meets is what they seem.

According to a plot summary at BookTrust, the Ender renting Callie's body plans to commit murder.

But the Body Bank offers a promise of much-needed cash - Prime Destinations pays the teenage Starters to rent out their bodies to wealthy Enders, giving them a chance to experience being young again. Yet for Callie, this chance to quickly raise some money soon becomes even more sinister when she discovers her renter intends to use her body to commit a murder.

I found an interview on YouTube where the author explains the premise of the book in her own words:

LISSA PRICE: It's set in a futuristic Los Angeles where desperate teens are renting out their bodies to seniors, so they can enjoy being young again, temporarily. One senior plans to do more than party and do sports with the body; she plans to use it to murder someone.
[...]
Right before the book starts was an incident called the Spore Wars and these were deadly spores that were unleashed in missiles across America. And what happened was people that had the vaccine survived this, but if you didn't have the vaccine, you didn't. And because the vaccine was in shortage, they only gave it to the very young and the very old; the most vulnerable members of society. And so what I call the middles or the parents are the ones then that didn't have the vaccine and they died. So that's how you get this world of young people and the elderly.
[...]
So, poor Callie. If you have grandparents, you could go live with them after this war, but if you didn't have them, you had to be put into institutions, which was a horrible thing; it was like a workhouse. And she's got a younger brother who's sick and she wants to protect him. So against her better wishes, she goes into Prime Destinations, a place where she can rent out her body, for a lot of money, to a senior. And of course, like everything, it goes well the first time; she goes to sleep, wakes up, everything is fine. Second time goes fine, and the third time is wrong and she wakes up in the life of her rich renter living in a mansion.




A preview of the book is available to read at Google Books.
